# P2P between peers in natted networks when the external port changes constantly

Tags: networking, webrtc, p2p, stun, hole-punching

I was reading up on WebRTC which led me to start looking into STUN (Session Traversal Utilities for NAT) and all the examples I saw seemed to assume that the public ip and port were static over at least several seconds or minutes at a time.

However, my home internet connection uses a shared public ip and putting the following php code

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . ":" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'];
?>
```

on a server with a public ip address gives results like this

```
63.142.201.34:34850
63.142.201.34:34924
etc.
```

when the page is refreshed repeatedly. The same thing happens with my cell phone when it is using my data plan (just with a different public ip).

How are peer-to-peer connections possible in this case? Can someone point me to a tutorial or some keywords I could use to look this up?

Dustin Soodak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing a different external port is that you are using different local ports, one for each HTTP request. That is rather common with TCP.

UDP as a connectionless protocol makes it easier to reuse the local port.
The tailscale project recently wrote up a great blog post on hole punching [here](https://tailscale.com/blog/how-nat-traversal-works/)

Comment: Thank you for both the suggestion to use UDP and the blog post link!

Comment: If I were to create functions Peer1IPandPort() & Peer2IPandPort(), which WebRTC functions would I use them in?